# How to run multiple sheel file in a line of bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have test1.sh (echo test1), and test2.sh (echo test2), I want to run the two shell file in a line:

```
~/dotfiles/scripts/{test1,test2}.sh
```

It seems only `test1.sh` is ran.

Comment: `for script in ~/dotfiles/scripts/{test1,test2}.sh; do bash "$script"; done`

Comment: Also to clarify, your command is equivalent to `~/dotfiles/scripts/test1.sh ~/dotfiles/scripts/test2.sh`, which calls `test1.sh` with `test2.sh` as its argument.

Comment: If parallel `parallel -u :::  ~/dotfiles/scripts/{test1,test2}.sh`

Comment: You need a semicolon between test1.sh and test2.sh, but `{test1,test2} creates a space between the expanded alternatives.

Comment: Also, it is not clear why you labelled this as bash **and** zsh.